# Как получить значение строкового ресурса по его имени

Tags: java, android, android-resources

Доброе время суток!

Есть web страница. Этой странице направляется GET запрос. Параметр запроса хранится в ресурсах в файле `strings.xml`.

```
<string name="value">2af54c32</string>
```

Параметр 100% корректный. Но, при формировании строки вместо того значения, которое хранится в ресурсах получаю `2131099673`. То есть, строковый параметр каким-то образом преобразован в десятичную систему счисления.
Строку запроса формирую следующим образом:

```
String site="http://example.com?id=";
String url=site+R.string.value;
```

Как избежать такого преобразования строк? В чём моя ошибка?

Comment: Здесь такая штука, что 2af54c32 = 720718898 в десятичной системе, то есть ни о каких преобразованиях речи не идет, 2131099673 - ID вашей строки в файле ресурсов класса `R`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ресурсы в андроиде при компиляции получают числовой ID, по коему можно получать к ним доступ. В вашем случае ресурсу был присвоен ID `2131099673`.

Для удобства пользования эти ID в коде применяются в виде `R.ТИП_РЕСУРСА.ИМЯ РЕСУРСА` (т.е. это `public final static int` поля класса `R`)

Получать же ресурсы нужно специальными методами класса `Context`. В случае строк вам надо пользоваться методом `getString(int ID)`:

```
String value = context.getString(R.string.value);
//или 
//String value = context.getResources().getString(R.string.value);
```

Стоит заметить, что при использовании данного кода в активити, указание класса context можно опустить, так как `Activity` сама наследуется от `Context`. То есть просто -

```
String value = getString(R.string.value);
//иди
//String value = getResources().getString(R.string.value);
```

Comment: Огромнейшее спасибо!!! Помогло!

Comment: Стоит заметить, что при использовании данного кода в активити, указание класса `context` можно опустить, так как `Activity` сама наследуется от `Context`. То есть просто - `String value = getString(R.string.value);` и `String value = getResources().getString(R.string.value);`

Comment: @pavlofff, действительно) Добавил в ответ.

Comment: @pavlofff, я не уверен, что ваша правка вопроса была нужна... Для разбирающихся в теме заголовок не очень подходит к сути вопроса, но, тем не менее, именно так ТС вопрос задал. Думаю, другие люди могут сей вопрос гуглить как раз по этому заголовку, так что его можно вернуть. Ну и метки убранные, думаю, не слишком мешали. Может откатим? =)

Comment: Я считаю, что данный вопрос не имеет никакого отношения к каким бы то ни было преобразованиям строк в любом смысле (и исходит из заблуждения автора о том, что он получил десятичное представление своего шестнадцатеричного числа, хотя по факту - никак не связанный с этим ID). По такому заголовку мало кто догадается, что его ожидает в ответе. Насчет меток - sdk тут никаким боком не затрагивается, development - метка парная основной и две они - перебор.